# lua - invalid argument type

Tags: lua, arguments, torch

I am a newbie to Lua. Currently getting the following error message:

```
invalid argument type for argument -model (should be the model checkpoint 
to use for sampling)
Usage: [options] <model>
```

I am sure it is something pretty easy to solve, but cannot manage to find the solution.

The 'model' is a file lm_checkpoint_epoch50.00_2.7196.t7, which is in the directory

```
/home/ubuntu/xxx/nn/cv
```

I am running the program from the parent directory (/home/ubuntu/xxx/nn)

I have tried out the following options to run the program (from one directory above the one the model is saved):

```
th sample.lua - model lm_chelm_checkpoint_epoch50.00_2.5344.t7
th sample.lua lm_chelm_checkpoint_epoch50.00_2.5344.t7
th sample.lua /cv/lm_chelm_checkpoint_epoch50.00_2.5344.t7
th sample.lua - /cv/model lm_chelm_checkpoint_epoch50.00_2.5344.t7
```

Also, the program has a torch.CmdLine() object where :argument equals '/cv/lm_checkpoint_epoch50.00_2.7196.t7'. The program prints the parameters, so that you see the following output on the screen:

```
Options
<model>      /cv/lm_checkpoint_epoch50.00_2.7196.t7
```

so it finds a value for argument 'model', which is picked up from the .lua file, not the parameter in the command line. This file is a valid mode.

Pretty lost, hope someone relates to this issue. Thanks.

Comment: seems like a bug. can you give a script to reproduce this? I can take a look.

Comment: hi there, yes it is a bug indeed. I am elaborating below. Thanks a lot smhx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the issue - it was a bug as smhx suggested. I inadvertently changed the source code from:

```
require 'torch'
cmd = torch.CmdLine()
cmd:argument('-model','model checkpoint to use for sampling')
```

Note that there is no argument in the source code. To:

```
cmd:argument('-model','/cv/model lm_chelm_checkpoint_epoch50.00_2.5344.t7'
'model checkpoint to use for sampling')
```

So the argument must be passed through the command line, not the source code. With parameters, it is different - you can include them in the source code.

So if I change back the source code and run the following from the command line:

```
th sample.lua cv/lm_chelm_checkpoint_epoch50.00_2.5344.t7
```

it works.